# Is there a way to make a nested loop with as many loops as you like (python)?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

The thing i'm trying to do is to create every single combination, but only using one of each letter

I did it with 3 sets of letters

```
inlist = ["Aa", "Bb", "Cc"]
outlist = []

for i in inlist[0]:
    for j in inlist[1]:
        for k in inlist[2]:
            outlist.append(str(i + j + k))
```

Output: 
outlist = ['ABC', 'ABc', 'AbC', 'Abc', 'aBC', 'aBc', 'abC', 'abc']

What if i want to do this with 2 or 4 sets of letters? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Check `itertools.product` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) does exactly that:

```
from itertools import product

inlist = ["Aa", "Bb", "Cc"]
outlist = []

for abc in product(*inlist):
    outlist.append(''.join(abc))

print(outlist)
# ['ABC', 'ABc', 'AbC', 'Abc', 'aBC', 'aBc', 'abC', 'abc']
```

`abc` is a tuple going from `('A', 'B', 'C')` to `('a', 'b', 'c')`. the only thing left to to is `join` that back to a string with `''.join(abc)`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> inlist = ["Aa", "Bb", "Cc"]
>>> [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(*inlist)]
['ABC', 'ABc', 'AbC', 'Abc', 'aBC', 'aBc', 'abC', 'abc']
```